# Creating lightweight Linq2Sql proxy objects

Tags: linq-to-sql, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to send my Linq2Sql objects to my jQuery plugins via JSON, preferably without additional code for each class.

The EntitySets are the main issue as they cause not only recursion, but when recursion is ignored (using [JSON.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/json)'s ReferenceLoopHandling feature) a silly amount of data can be retrieved, when I only really need 1 or 2 levels.  This gets really bad when you're talking about Users, Roles and Permissions as you get the User's Role, the User's Permissions, the Role's Permissions, and the Role's Users all up in your JSON before it hits recursion and stops.  Compare this to what I actually want, which is just the RoleId.

My initial approach was to send a "simplified" version of the object, where I reflect the entity and set any EntitySets to null, but of course in the above example Roles gets set to null and so RoleId is null.  Setting only the 2nd level properties to null kind of works but there's still too much data as the EntitySets that weren't killed (the first level ones) repopulate their associated tables when the JsonSerializer does its reflection and I still get all those Permission objects that I just don't need.

I definately don't want to get into the situation of creating a lightweight version of every class and implementing "From" and "To" style methods on them, as this is a lot of work and seems wasteful.

Another option is to put a JsonIgnoreAttribute on the relevant properties, but this is going to cause a nightmare scenario whenever classes need to be re-generated.

My current favourite solution which I like and hate at the same time is to put the classes into opt-in serialization mode, but because I can't add attributes to the real properties I'd have to create JSON-only properties in a partial class.  Again, this seems wasteful but I think it's the best so far.

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the Serialization Mode in the dbml file?

It's a standard property under code generation and when you set it to Unidirectional it won't generate all the additional levels of your table structure. I've used this with silverlight and WCF to send data because the data contracts don't allow for additional levels to be sent (silverlight is very limited on what you can and can't do).

Hope this helps!